# How to implement hmset in Lettuce Command Interface Commands

Tags: java, redis, lettuce

I am trying to invoke hmset command from Lettuce Command Interface Commands
But at runtime it gives error

> Command HMSET requires at least 3 parameters but method declares 2 parameter(s). Offending method: public abstract java.lang.Void net.media.max.utils.LettuceCommandInterface.hmset(java.lang.String,java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.String>)

below is my class

```java
import java.util.Map;

import io.lettuce.core.dynamic.Commands;
import io.lettuce.core.dynamic.annotation.Command;
import io.lettuce.core.dynamic.batch.BatchExecutor;
import io.lettuce.core.dynamic.batch.BatchSize;

@BatchSize(1000)
public interface LettuceCommandInterface extends Commands, BatchExecutor {
    @Command("HSET")
    void hset(String key, String hashKey, String value);
    
    @Command("ZADD")
    void zadd(String key, double score, String member);

    @Command("SET")
    void set(String key, String values);

    @Command("hmset")
    Void hmset(String key, Map<String,String> map);

}
```

If I replace the void with String as the return type then it gives the following error

> Batching command method public abstract java.lang.String net.media.max.utils.LettuceCommandInterface.hmset(java.lang.String,java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.String>) must declare either a Future or void return type

Answer (score 0):

I've met the question as you too.
I found that when creating the factory, will read command metadata from the Redis server. Then use metadata to verify the method parameters conform to the specification.

```
this.commandMethodVerifier = new DefaultCommandMethodVerifier(getCommands(connection));
```

However, hmset command requires at least 4 parameters to be passed in：

```
HMSET usage: HMSET key field value [field value...]
COMMAND return: 
1) "hmset"
2) (integer) -4
3)  1) write
    2) denyoom
4) (integer) 1
5) (integer) 1
6) (integer) 1
```

I resolved the issue by modifying the method as follows：

```
void hmset(String key, String field, String value, String... fieldvalues);
```